# How to handle GPIO interrupt-like handling in Linux userspace

Tags: c++, linux, gpio

Not sure whether I should post this here or not but I gotta ask.

Context :

- Linux on an embedded platform (CPU @~500MHz)
- One team working on the single userspace software
- One team working on Linux + driver + uboot etc.

The software has to handle GPIO, some are output (write when needed), some are input (read when needed for some, preferably interrupt-like for others).

The software is a multi-threaded app with ~10-15 threads in SCHED_FIFO scheduling policy.

Let's say I have a module called WGPIO which is a wrapper handling GPIO. (this is developed by the Linux team btw. WGPIO is still in user-space, but they could develop a driver if needed)

Here is some pseudo_code of what is designed as we speak.

```
gpio_state state = ON;
// IO_O is output. Set to ON, don't care if it's active_high or active_low btw
WGPIO_WriteOutput(IO_O,state);

// IO_I is input, read when needed
WGPIO_ReadInput(IO_I,&state);

// register callback when rising edge occurs on IO named IO_IT
WGPIO_SetCallback(IO_IT,EDGE_RISING,my_callback);
// Unmask to enable further IT-like processing
WGPIO_UnmaskIRQ(IO_IT);
```

I must be able to handle some of the GPIO changes in 5 to 10ms.

Is some userspace polling (WGPIO would have a SCHED_FIFO thread then) on multiple FDs enough to simulate an "interrupt-like" handling in my app ? This looks like the most simple idea.

If you need more details, feel free to ask.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [kernel gpio/sysfs.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt):

> ```
> "value" ... reads as either 0 (low) or 1 (high). If the GPIO
>   is configured as an output, this value may be written;
>   any nonzero value is treated as high.
>
>   If the pin can be configured as interrupt-generating interrupt
>   and if it has been configured to generate interrupts (see the
>   description of "edge"), you can poll(2) on that file and
>   poll(2) will return whenever the interrupt was triggered. If
>   you use poll(2), set the events POLLPRI and POLLERR. If you
>   use select(2), set the file descriptor in exceptfds. After
>   poll(2) returns, either lseek(2) to the beginning of the sysfs
>   file and read the new value or close the file and re-open it
>   to read the value.
>
> "edge" ... reads as either "none", "rising", "falling", or
>   "both". Write these strings to select the signal edge(s)
>   that will make poll(2) on the "value" file return.
>
>   This file exists only if the pin can be configured as an
>   interrupt generating input pin.
> ```

The preferred way is usually to configure the interrupt with `/sys/class/gpio/gpioN/edge` and `poll(2)` for `POLLPRI | POLLERR` (important it's *not* POLLIN!) on `/sys/class/gpio/gpioN/value`. If your process is some "real-time" process that needs to handle the events in real time, consider decreasing it's niceness.

You can even find some example code on github that uses poll, ex. [this repo](https://github.com/luisaburini/GPIO-interrupt/blob/master/gpio-poll.c).

Comment: The poll(2) solution was already the original idea, I wanted to see it there were some more efficient/whatever idea. I accept your answer since it should work and answer my question. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't call this "the preferred way" when the document you linked to clearly says at the beginning that this interface is deprecated and should not be used. I'm still looking for a solution using the new API.

Comment: I think libgpiod wasn't that popular at the time this was written. But sure - let's mention it.